# Visual Studio 2017 csproj adds "weird" files on package install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, csproj

I have some issues with my VS2017 csproj's(https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/). When I install certain nuget packages, I'd get some additional files being added to my project and most of the time the dependency is not even working properly. It does not do that on older csproj's.

Two examples:

- I have one "home made" nuget (made out of a VS2017 csproj too) which is supposed to transform the local app.config of the target project on install and uninstall (basically adding a line on install and removing it on uninstlal). On a older csproj, it does what it needs to do. With a VS2017 csproj, it will not do the transform but add the two transform files to the projects.
- I need to install the package named "CefSharp.OffScreen" on one of my projects. On an older one it works like a charm. On a VS2017 csproj the dependency is not even there (it has a "!" in front) and it adds two "x64" and "x86" directories with tons of files ("dll's" etc.) in there.

Is there something known about issues like that with VS2017 projects ?

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Are you adding .NET Framework libraries to a .NET Standard or Core project?

Comment: The vs2017 csproj's are .NET framework (target 4.6.2) projects, not standard or core one's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something known about issues like that with VS2017 projects ?

For the **first example**, That because xdt transforms **aren't supported** in `PackageReference` environment. This includes both sdk-based projects as well as classic .net framework projects using `PackageReference` instead of `packages.config`. You can follow [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5954) for more details. There is also a [sample package](https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/master/XDTransformExample) that shows how to use build-time logic to apply transforms instead to work in all environments.

For the **second example**, you can find a `CefSharp.Common.targets` file in the `\build` folder in the dependency package `CefSharp.Common`, in this `.target` file, you can see following code:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <CefSharpCommonBinaries32 Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\CefSharp\x86\*.*" />
    <CefSharpCommonBinaries64 Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\CefSharp\x64\*.*" />
    <CefSharpCommonBinariesAnyCPU Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\CefSharp\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

With this .target file, nuget will including files under the `x64` and `x86` folder to your project.

In the old `.csproj` project, that `.target` file imported by following code after install the nuget packages, you can check it in your project file `.csproj`:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\CefSharp.Common.63.0.3\build\CefSharp.Common.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\CefSharp.Common.63.0.3\build\CefSharp.Common.targets')" />
```

Those files under the x86 and x64 folder would be imported when the project is running.

When you use the new `.csproj` project, the .target file imported by the file `project.assets.json`, all the files will be imported to the project when you save the `.target` in the `project.assets.json`.

That is the reason why you got those tons of dll files after install the package package `CefSharp.Common`. So, this is not a issue, but because they import `.targets` in different ways.

If you do not want show those dll files in your project, you can return back the `packages.config`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It pretty much answers all my iquestions but also lowers my expectations :D